# Gerrit build posting comments from post build actions in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, gerrit, gerrit-trigger, sonar-gerrit

I have integrated Sonar gerrit plugin to post sonar reports as comment in the gerrit web ui.
Posting the sonar comments is configured in the post build action of the gerrit build to be posted under sonar-verified category.Verified scoring is posted by the gerrit build's success/failure.

But sonar violations comments are posted as part of verified scoring.

this is also not consistent. sometimes the sonar violation comments are properly posted under sonar-verified category.[image: Screenshot of the issue]

Probably the scoring on two different labels happens in two different threads and comments are posted whichever finishes first
Please find the attached screenshot

Best Regards,
Saurav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You have answered your question yourself. Suggestion: add a dummy post-build action before the "Post SonarQube issues" to introduce a delay (like "sleep 10) to workaround this issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot Marcelo for your suggestion..i introduced sleep in the windows batch command as a build step and its working